# JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken throwing Lifetime validation failed exception

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an ASP.net core 5 Web API. While trying to get a refresh token, various validation checks are done on the current token. My initial check is using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken with the code below.

`var tokenInVerification = jwtTokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenRequest.Token, _tokenValidationParams, out var validatedToken);`

However it throws:

`IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'`

Is there anyway to get around this since I would not want it to throw the exception but continue so I can run other validation checks.

I am iterating [over](https://dev.to/moe23/refresh-jwt-with-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-5-rest-api-step-by-step-3en5)

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to ignore lifetime validation. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Just set `ValidateLifetime=false` in `_tokenValidationParams`

```
var _tokenValidationParams= new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = GetValidAudience(),
    ValidIssuer = GetValidIssuer(),
    IssuerSigningKey = GetIssuerSigningKey(),
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,

    ValidateLifetime = false //Here we are saying that we don't care about the token's expiration date
};
```

Comment: Although this suppresses the error it doesn't tell the user that the token is invalid after set time.

Comment: @wooldon As far as I understand you want to check your current token and receive refresh token. I can't think of any reason why you care about expire time of current token because if current token is valid there is no reason to request refresh token. By the way if you need to check each validation why don't you call ValidateToken several times with different validationParams inside different try catch to check different validation?

Comment: I solved it by using a different set of TokenValidationParameters in side my  VerifyAndGenerateToken function. The TokenValidationParameters in my startup has ValidateLifetime = true while the one in the VerifyAndGenerateToken function is set to false. This way I can test the expiry date myself whilst using JwtSecurityTokenHandler for its purpose in validation.